# Static method Math#random invocation in Thymeleaf using OGNL gets OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "lang")

Tags: java, thymeleaf, ognl

I'm trying a very basic static Java method invocation by Thymeleaf:

```html
<div th:text="${T(java.lang.Math).random()}"/>
```

But always got the exception `OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "lang")`.

Full error message:

```
2023-08-11 16:17:16,221 ERROR [etp1561005241-55] o.t.TemplateEngine [THYMELEAF][etp1561005241-55] Exception processing template "test.html": Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "T(java.lang.Math).random(
)" (template: "test.html" - line 89, col 14)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "T(java.lang.Math).random()" (template: "diag-ui.html" - line 89, col 14)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:199)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:104)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
        at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228)
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1064)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1053)
        at hobbit.mordor.diagui.DiaguiEndpoint.handleSearch(DiaguiEndpoint.java:106)
        at hobbit.mordor.diagui.DiaguiEndpoint.handle(DiaguiEndpoint.java:149)
        at hobbit.mordor.server.JettyRequestHandler.dispatchRequest(JettyRequestHandler.java:273)
        at hobbit.mordor.server.JettyRequestHandler.handle(JettyRequestHandler.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "lang")
```

Comment: I've never used Thymeleaf or OGNL, but looking at other pages, I suspect `${@java.lang.Math@random()}` is what you want (or possibly even just `${@random()}`). Unfortunately I'm not in a position to check that at the moment.

Comment: Depending on your versions and other settings, there are [various syntaxes](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/593) to try.

Comment: Just testet your code and it works fine. So the code itself is alright, might be a setup problem with your TemplateEngine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

`${@java.lang.Math@random()}` worked for me

Comment: Remember, other people may encounter a similar problem and a Google search may include this post in the search results. Do you think your answer will be enough for them to understand how to solve their problem? Personally, I don't think so. Maybe you could add some more explanation on where, in the code, `${@java.lang.Math@random()}` needs to be located?